# Process.Start keeps steam game running even after it has shutdown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process, steam

I am modding a unity application (on Steam). I am calling `Process.Start` on a `.txt` file, which opens (for me) in Notepad++.

The problem is that even after I close the game, Steam still thinks that it's running, and I can't open it again until I close Notepad++.

I am trying to find a workaround for this, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Kill the process when the game ends? Note that you should use the `-multiInst` argument on the command line

Comment: I don't really want to kill the process when the game ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the local shell (like bash on linux and cmd or powershell on windows) to run it (eg. `bash` with commandline arguments `-c path/to/notepad++`) and it would create a standalone process.